# How to default export an object of other imported types in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I am trying to provide ambient type definitions for a JavaScript package of utility classes (let's say something like Lodash). I want users to be able to import modules in the following ways:

```js
// TypeScript or Babel

import myutils from 'myutils' // myutils = { a: [Function], b: [Function] }
import { a } from 'myutils'   // a: Function
import a from 'myutils/a'     // a: Function

// JavaScript

const myutils = require('myutils') // myutils = { a: [Function], b: [Function] }
const { a } = require('myutils')   // a: Function
const a = require('myutils/a')     // a: Function
```

The code is structured like this:

```js
// a.js
module.exports = () => 'a'
```

```js
// b.js
module.exports = () => 'b'
```

```js
// index.js
module.exports = { a: require('./a'), b: require('./b') }
```

My problem is that I cannot manage to write proper TypeScript ambient definitions for these. So far I have:

```js
// a.d.ts
export default function a(): string
```

```js
// b.d.ts
export default function b(): string
```

```js
// index.d.ts
export { default as a } from './a'
export { default as b } from './b'

export default ...what?
```

I also tried this with no success:

```js
// index.d.ts
import a from './a'
import b from './b'

export { a, b }

// Member 'a' implicitly has an 'any' type, but a better type may be inferred from usage.ts(7045)
declare const _default: { a, b }

export default _default
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're using the functions `a` and `b` as type when doing this:

```js
declare const _default: { a, b }
```

Using `typeof a` instead should fix the error:

```js
declare const _default: {
    a: typeof a,
    b: typeof b
}
```

[Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEAzArgOzAFwJYHtXygAoBKALngDcctgBuAKFElgRXWz3gCMTyqaG9EAA8ADjhgZ4AbwIAabvAC+9RuGhx4YPAGcpAfVCIoyCBnLT68AuQwBPUSByJ5V7rYdOXXeiqFiJKSMTM3hDEGNTDCA)